# Why doesn't this swap expression work as intended?

Tags: python

It is a basic selection sort that I tried to write with Python.

```
arr = [64,12,35,312,45,12,50,80,0,4,6,8,92]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i], arr[arr.index(min(arr[i:]))] = arr[arr.index(min(arr[i:]))], arr[i]
```

However, the swap expression doesn't work. There clearly is something I don't know about Python that comes to play here. What is it?

Comment: For a start I'd set `j = arr.index(min(arr[i:]))`, and use `arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]`.  Also print `j`.  The idea is to make the code clearer, and make sure it is using the indices that you expect.

Comment: @hpaulj That's clearly the way to go. I just want to know the mistake here. Learning why something "doesn't" work as expected also makes me learn a lot :)

Comment: We have to be ware of when different quantities get evaluated.  `a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]` swap works fine with lists (but not with numpy arrays).  So the remaining issue is making sure the index is evaluated correctly for both sides of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This is because first the r.h.s is computed and then, during value unpacking, for each item on the l.h.s `__setitem__` gets called, one after another. That means when the l.h.s `arr[arr.index(...)]` is computed the first assignment `arr[i] = arr[arr.index(...)]` has already taken place and hence modified the array. For that reason the l.h.s. `arr.index(...)` does not necessarily return the same value as the r.h.s counterpart.

We can visualize this with the following snippet:

```
class Test:
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        print(f'get {x}')
        return x

    def __setitem__(self, x, y):
        print(f'set {x}={y}')


class Index:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.x})'


test = Test()
test[Index(0)], test[Index(1)] = test[Index(2)], test[Index(3)]
```

Which outputs:

```
Index(2)
get Index(2)
Index(3)
get Index(3)
Index(0)
set Index(0)=Index(2)
Index(1)
set Index(1)=Index(3)
```

Also check the [docs about evaluation order of expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order).

#### More detailed breakdown of specific example

For your specific example, using the index of the minimum value, this results in a no-op. These are the steps that happen in order:

1. R.h.s. `arr.index(min(arr[i:]))` is evaluated (it's going to be something, let's call it `m`), then `arr[m]` is evaluated (let's call it `a`; this is the minimum element of `arr[i:]`).
2. R.h.s. `arr[j]` is evaluated (let's call it `b`).
3. L.h.s. `arr.__setitem__(i, a)` is evaluated, setting the element at index `i` to the minimum value (`a`).
4. L.h.s. `arr.__setitem__(arr.index(min(arr[i:])), b)` is evaluated. Because of the previous operation (3.) the `arr.index(min(arr[i:]))` is going to be `i` now. For that reason the element at index `i` is set to `b` which was the previous `arr[i]`, i.e. it is set back to its previous value, resulting in a no-op.

Instead you can compute the index beforehand:

```
index = arr.index(min(arr[i:]))
a[i], a[index] = a[index], a[i]
```